# Why does Firefox remove TR and TD strings when using innerHTML on the parent

Tags: jquery, html

I'm getting a HTML fragment back from an ajax call. I'm using jQuery and only want the TR within the fragment. Using jQuery selectors to find the TR yields nothing in Firefox, only IE.

So as a workaround I thought I might try

```
$(ajaxString).filter('form').first().html()
```

and also

```
$(ajaxString).filter('form').first()[0].innerHTML
```

Those two methods only worked in IE, in Firefox, the TR and TD elements are gone and only the span is returned. What's the problem and solution? :-)

```
<form method="post">
 <tr>
   <td><span> stuff </span></td>
 <tr>
<form>
```

Comment: `<tr>` has to be a direct child of `<table>`, invalid tags are cleaned when the browser parses the HTML into the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Firefox error corrects invalid elements being wrapped around table rows, it places that element after the end of the table in the DOM.

i.e. it doesn't remove them when using innerHTML, it removes them when parsing the not-really-HTML in the first place.

The relationship between a form and a table can either be "The table is in a form" or "The form is in a table cell".

Comment: That's a bit silly but correct nonetheless! Looks like IE scores points in my good books this time.

Comment: No browser should be awarded any points for handling completely wrong code in a specific way. They are just making the best of a really bad situation.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML fragment should be a valid one. Something like

```
<form method="post">
   <table>
     <tr>
        <td><span> stuff </span></td>
     <tr>
   </table>
<form>
```

Then you can use something like

```
$(ajaxString).find("form").html();
```

Comment: I don't need the whole table just a row insert. I suppose it's a work around for now. Thanks.